# difference in argument used in function call and function definition

Tags: c++, function

started learning C++ recently and i don't understand why when defining a function such as

```
void change_value (int &b);
```

but when you do a function call in main,

```
int test = 10;
change_value (test);
```

you do not use &test but rather use the variable itself (test).

Answer (score 0):

`&` has different meanings in different contexts.

The `b` parameter uses `&` to declare that it is a [*reference*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) to an `int`. The `&` is part of the parameter type (`int&`). When calling the function, you just pass in the `int` variable that you want `b` to refer to, and the reference will be bound to that variable.

If the caller  were to preceed the `int` variable it is passing in with `&`, that will invoke the `address-of` operator to get the *address* of the variable, producing a [*pointer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) to the variable.

A *reference* and a *pointer* are two completely difference things.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau perhaps put some code snippets - because I presume you mean in the function call - ie.. `some_other_function (&test);` for the address-of comment (although that doesn't have anything to do with the OP it is useful if the context is given).

Comment: @MrR Why _"in the function call"_ only? You can take an object address for whatever purpose you want, not just function call arguments.

Comment: True but the OP is about function calls - so just suggesting that the answers should be clear about context - i.e. put in good examples makes the answer more useful.